# Issue with "Object.keys" on IE 11

Tags: admin-on-rest

I've an issue on IE only, no issue on Chrome or Safari.

It gave me this error: "Object.keys : l’argument n’est pas un objet Object".

I need IE support here since it's for an intranet app that need to provide file:// links (so IE and trusted sites for Windows).

We've the issue on IE 11.

Comment: Could you show us the code, so we can test on our site?

Answer (score 0):

Use [babel-polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/).

```
npm install --save babel-polyfill
```

Import it at the top of your `src/index.js`.